# 3-layer feedfoward neural network not predicting regression values accurately

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, regression

I'm pretty new to Tensorflow. Currently, I'm doing a 3-layer network, with 10 neurons in the hidden layer with ReLU, mini-batch gradient descent size of 8, L2 regularisation weight decay parameter (beta) of 0.001. The Tensorflow version I'm using is 1.14 and I'm on Python 3.6.

The issue that boggles my mind is that my predicted values and testing errors are absolutely *off the charts*.

For example, I plotted out the test errors and the predicted vs target values for a sample size of 50, [and this is what came out.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoUiT.png)
As you can see, both plots are way off, and I haven't had the slightest clue as to why.

[Here's how the dataset roughly looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdgOy.png) The first column is discarded as it is just a counter value, and the last column is the target.

My code:

```
NUM_FEATURES = 7
num_neuron = 10
batch_size = 8
beta = 0.001
learning_rate = 0.001

epochs = 4000
seed = 10
np.random.seed(seed)

# read and divide data into test and train sets
total_dataset= np.genfromtxt('dataset_excel.csv', delimiter=',')
X_data, Y_data = total_dataset[1:, 1:8], total_dataset[1:, -1]
Y_data = Y_data.reshape(Y_data.shape[0], 1)

# shuffle input, ensure both are shuffled with the same order
shufflestate = np.random.get_state()
np.random.shuffle(X_data)
np.random.set_state(shufflestate)
np.random.shuffle(Y_data)

# 70% used for training, 30% used for testing
trainX = X_data[:280]
trainY = Y_data[:280]
testX = X_data[280:]
testY = Y_data[280:]

trainX = (trainX - np.mean(trainX, axis=0)) / np.std(trainX, axis=0)

# Create the model
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, NUM_FEATURES])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])

# get 50 samples for plotting of predicted vs target values
limited50testX = testX[:50]
limited50testY = testY[:50]

# Hidden
with tf.name_scope('hidden'):
    weight1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([NUM_FEATURES, num_neuron],stddev=1.0,name='weight1'))
    bias1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_neuron]),name='bias1')
    hidden = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x, weight1) + bias1)

# output
with tf.name_scope('linear'):
    weight2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_neuron, 1],stddev=1.0 / np.sqrt(float(num_neuron))),name='weight2')
    bias2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]),name='bias2')
    logits = tf.matmul(hidden, weight2) + bias2

ridgeLoss = tf.square(y_ - logits)
regularisation = tf.nn.l2_loss(weight1) + tf.nn.l2_loss(weight2)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(ridgeLoss + beta * regularisation)

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
error = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_ - logits))

N = len(trainX)
idx = np.arange(N)

predicted=[]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    train_err = []
    test_err_ = []
    
    for i in range(epochs):
        for batchStart, batchEnd in zip(range(0, trainX.shape[0], batch_size),range(batch_size, trainX.shape[0], batch_size)):
            train_op.run(feed_dict={x: trainX[batchStart:batchEnd], y_: trainY[batchStart:batchEnd]})
        err = error.eval(feed_dict={x: trainX, y_: trainY})
        train_err.append(err)
        
            
        if i % 100 == 0:
            print('iter %d: train error %g' % (i, train_err[i]))
        test_err = error.eval(feed_dict={x: testX, y_: testY})
        test_err_.append(test_err)

    predicted = sess.run(logits, feed_dict={x:limited50testX})
    print("predicted values: ", predicted)
    print("size of predicted values is", len(predicted))
    
    print("targets: ", limited50testY)
    print("size of target values is", len(limited50testY))

#plot predictions vs targets
numberList=np.arange(0, 50, 1).tolist()
predplot = plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(numberList, predicted, label='Predictions')
plt.plot(numberList, limited50testY, label='Targets')
plt.xlabel('50 samples')
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
predplot.show()

# plot training error
trainplot = plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(range(epochs), train_err)
plt.xlabel(str(epochs) + ' iterations')
plt.ylabel('Train Error')
trainplot.show()

#plot testing error
testplot = plt.figure(3)
plt.plot(range(epochs), test_err_)
plt.xlabel(str(epochs) + ' iterations')
plt.ylabel('Test Error')
testplot.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if that's it, but `trainX` is normalized whereas `testX` is not. You might want to use the same normalization on `testX` before predicting.